# GDAL/OGR- OGRLayer.Intersection() with C# bindings

Tags: ogr, intersection

I was trying to perform intersection on two feature classes (shapefile
format) using OGRLayer.Intersection(), but have problems making it work
with C# bindings. I am not able to figure out on how to pass the
arguments SWIGTYPE_p_GDALProgressFunc callback
and OSGeo.OGR.SWIGTYPE_p_void callback_data.

Can someone please help me figure out on how to handle these. I keep getting the error: `"Attempt to dereference null GDALProgressFunc".`

I am not sure what that means.

Please share an example on how to call Intersection routine or some other
routine which takes above mentioned argument types.